# Concatenate multiple digits in different rows into one integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame of a single column made of 30000 rows each housing an individual integer like 1, 2, 4, 7, 9, etc.
I want to concatenate the digits of every 50 rows into one single digit. So the number of rows will change from 30000 to 30000/50 = 600 rows each housing a single integer made of concatenating 50 rows.
So digits like 1, 2, 4, 7, 9, ... 3 (50 of them) will turn into one integer 12479...3 occupying one cell or row and so on for the rest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if your input dataframe looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.random.randint(10, size=30000)})
```

---

```
       col
0        1
1        1
2        1
3        8
4        4
...    ...
29995    0
29996    2
29997    4
29998    2
29999    7

[30000 rows x 1 columns]
```

Then you can do this:

```
print(df.groupby(df.index // 50)['col'].agg(lambda x: ''.join(map(str, x))))
```

to print:

```
0      1118461343314944251078615718342449112249161558...
1      1747004710953641680211733510264626747570866618...
2      8121414590539954240646159491668057874649372193...
3      6752166006104257704233198888085209307579966492...
4      6894789891094181188516974222021527062663673212...
                             ...                        
595    9134173565553669597038089981125300730142452161...
596    4673218339922521922263861144391586968793317405...
597    3274562300781449881296937717538762105128040998...
598    4158802127883136581682677478655313834281219294...
599    6963604643343712867804357553402388236789039680...
Name: col, Length: 600, dtype: object
```